# How to assign multiple roles and multiple roles based permissions uning laravel spatie?

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, roles

I am working on a laravel project having role-based access to users like:

```
1 admin -> all permissions
2 creator -> add, edit and remove members
3 finance -> add fund, update fund

the problem is, a user, say "XYZ" has multiple roles like creator and finance and another user "PQR" has only finance
```

by using of "Spatie laravel permission" how can I achieve this?

Comment: A user can have many roles, read more in their documentation: https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v4/basic-usage/role-permissions you can simply assign multiple roles as array `$user->assignRole(['creator', 'finance']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For user "XYZ"**

We can pass relevant roles creator and finance as a array to controller,

then,

**$user->assignRole($request->role);**

*// $user->assignRole(['creator', 'finanace']) or $user->assignRole('creator','finance')*

**For user "PQR"**

Like above,

**$user->assignRole($request->role);**

*// $user->assignRole(['finance']);*

For further details, you can refer to the official documentation. https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v3/basic-usage/role-permissions

Comment: Thank you very much, you both gives me right direction